# AbortSignal.timeout() in fetch request always responds with AbortError but not TimeoutError

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have following code:

```js
const getData = async function () {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/cars`, {
      signal: AbortSignal.timeout(5_000),
    });

    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.name); //AbortError
    console.dir(err);
  }
};

getData();
```

Here, getData uses `fetch()` to retrieve data from an API endpoint, I set `signal` property of request to `AbortSignal.timeout(5_000)` to implement timeout.

According to MDN documentation, [`AbortSignal.timeout(TIME_IN_MS)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/timeout) will return `AbortSignal` that will automatically abort after specified time. The signal aborts with either `TimeoutError` on timeout, or with `AbortError` due to pressing a browser stop button, closing the tab (or some other inbuilt "stop" operation).

The response that I get every time when running `getData()` is `AbortError` with message `The user aborted a request.` and never `TimeoutError`, even when I set browser to throttle to slow 3G and set time to 100ms. I also tried setting the response to take 10s in the server and in the front end to no throttle and timeout to 9000ms.

Why don't I get `TimeoutError` but only get `AbortError`?

### Update 1:

This issue seems to only be for chromium-based browsers like Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge but works as Expected in Firefox.

### Update 2:

As pointed by @Kaiido, this seems to be error of not only Chromium but also Safari. Issue is opened on both:

- Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1431720
- Safari: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246069

Comment: Is `5_000` a typo?

Comment: @James no it's not a typo, it's numeric separator which was introduced to the language in ES2021 to improve readability of numeric literal, check out [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#literals).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a Chrome and Safari bug.

I just opened [CRBUG 1431754](https://crbug.com/1431754), and Safari had [BUG 246069](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246069) for quite some time now.

According to [the specs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#abort-fetch)

> To abort a `fetch()` call with a *promise*, *request*, *responseObject*, and an *error*:
>
> 1. Reject *promise* with *error*.

In this case you hit the *abort steps* set at the step 11 of the [`fetch()` method algorithm](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-global-fetch):

> 4.11 Abort the `fetch()` call with *p*, *request*, *responseObject*, and *requestObject*’s signal’s abort reason.

Here "*requestObject*’s signal’s abort reason" is the object stored in our `AbortSignal.reason`, so not only should we have the same kind of `DOMException`, but it should even be the same object.

Here is another test (hitting the step 4. this time, but the result is the same) that does repro the issue:

```js
(async () => {
  const signal = AbortSignal.timeout(0);
  // Wait for the signal times out
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res));
  const { reason } = signal;
  try {
   await fetch("./",{ signal });
  }
  catch(fetchErr) {
    console.log({
        reason: reason.name,      // Expected: "TimeoutError"
      fetchErr: fetchErr.name,  // Expected: "TimeoutError"
      same: fetchErr === reason // Expected: true
    });
  }
})();
```

Unfortunately I don't see what you can do about it... checking the original `AbortSignal#reason` at the time the `fetch()` promise rejects might do it, but that sounds a bit hackish and prone to false positives.

Comment: Yeah it's clearly a bug in chromium, I also had reported it about 10hours ago. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1431720

Comment: Han, I didn't find yours while looking for previous reports, weird...